# How to Get Colorful Table cell Dynamically in FDPF?

Tags: php, tcpdf, fpdf

Hi I am trying to make **colorful table row in fpdf** but i'm Confused how should I initate for it I am trying to do something like this:

[image: screenshot]

Yellow color row is header and 2 other are my data row which comes I am trying to put a logic if **even number row** then it's white color background and if odd then grey

Here is my code which i am trying to implements but no output is coming.

```
    $pageno = 2;
    $l = 1;
    for($i=0;$i<count($_GET);$i++){
        if($_GET[$i] !=''){
    if(!is_numeric($_GET[$i])){        
        $chngeRowBakGColor = $l % 2;
        if ($chngeRowBakGColor == 0) {
            $styleIndexRow = $styleCellIndexEven;
        } else {
            $styleIndexRow = $styleCellIndexOdd;
        }
        if(trim($_GET[$i])!="") {
            $printQueryResult = runPrintQuery($_GET[$i]);
            $totalRows = mysql_num_rows($printQueryResult);
            $resultArrayIndex = mysql_fetch_array($printQueryResult);
             $pdf->Cell(25,6,'Date',0,0,'L',True);
        $pdf->Cell(82,6,'Headlines',0,0,'L',True);
        $pdf->Cell(24,6,'Publications',0,0,'L',True);
        $pdf->Cell(20,6,'Edition',0,0,'R',True);
        $pdf->Cell(20,6,'Page no.',0,0,'R',True); 
        }
        $pageno = $pageno + $totalRows;
        $l++;
```

Comment: @NicoHaase no i doesn't because data is dynamic and huge also how could i automate colors in loop? it doesn't clarify anything

Comment: Well, as far as I see, you haven't used anything else to configure colors, or did I overlook it?